# delete vertices while preserving nodes IDs

Tags: igraph

I am using the function "delete vertices", and I found a strange behavior on my networks.
After reading the documentation of igraph, I found that:

"delete.vertices removes the specified vertices from the graph together with their adjacent edges. The ids of the vertices are not preserved."

is there any work-around to preserve the ids of the original network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assign a vertex attribute to the graph, probably the `name` attribute is best. These are kept after deletion.

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
V(g)$name <- letters[1:10]
g2 <- delete.vertices(g, c("a", "b", "f"))
str(g2)
# IGRAPH UN-- 7 5 -- Ring graph
# + attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l), name (v/c)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] c--d d--e g--h h--i i--j
```

If you want to preserve the original numeric vertex ids, then assign them as names:

```
gg <- graph.ring(10)
V(gg)$name <- V(gg)
gg2 <- delete.vertices(gg, c(1,2,6))
str(gg2)
# IGRAPH UN-- 7 5 -- Ring graph
# + attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l), name (v/n)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] 3-- 4 4-- 5 7-- 8 8-- 9 9--10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My original graph is an edge-list with the form:
1,2
2,10
1,15
....

I want to keep the numbers provided with that list i.e: 1,10,2,15
not a new naming or new numbering

Comment: Then assign these numbers as vertex names in the `name` attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to assign the original node number as a name for the node. I care about the original ids of the graph. IOW, if I have an edge "1 -> 2", then the node "1" should have a name "1" and node "2" should have a name "2"